# You are trying to add a non-nullable field stock without a default

Tags: django, django-models

I have added a new field in my model but after that I have deleted db.sqlite3 (to ensure I don't get error below)

```
agrawalo@:~/myapp> ls
README.md  config  core  manage.py  requirements.txt
```

But still I get this error when I run makemigrations

```
agrawalo@:~/myapp> ./manage.py makemigrations
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'high52' to stock without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py


class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    diff = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    open_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    previous_close = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    low52 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    high52 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = DataFrameManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        self.last_updated = timezone.now()
        return super(Stock, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.code)
```

low52 and high52 are the newly added fields. Please note that none of the other existing field throw this error.

Comment: Did you add any new field in your models?

Comment: I have added a new field in my model but after that I have deleted db.sqlite3 (to ensure I don't get error below)

Comment: It is not about deleting the database. It is about migrations. You either need to add a default value to the newly added field or make the field as optional. Make a decision based on your use case.

Comment: But there are no existing records, then why should it complain. How do I make field optional?

Comment: Add the code of newly added field in your question itself.

Comment: Added, please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either provide a default value to the field

```
high52 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
```

or you can make it optional

```
high52 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

You can make a decision based on your choice.

To answer your question about the error, the previously existing fields might have been created in the initial migration itself and they don't need a default value. But for the newly added field, you need a default value for mandatory fields and this default value will be populated in the existing records. This doesn't depend on whether you have deleted the existing database or not. This depends on the current state of migrations for that model. Since this is not the initial migration, you will need to provide a default value or make it optional.

Comment: Is there a way to force initial migration to happen again?

Comment: I mean is there a way to tell Django that this is a fresh installation of the application?

Comment: If your application is still in early stages of development and not deployed yet, you can try removing the already migration files and run `makemigrations` again. But this is advisable only in the very early stages of development.

Comment: Yes. The files which starts with `000` in the app's `migrations` directory.

Comment: I removed all of these but now I am getting "django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration core.0010_log_action dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'core', u'0009_log_isactive')
" It worked, I guess __pycache__ also needs to be deleted.

Comment: Could be. If any other migration depends on the deleted migrations, you will face this error.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if you deleted the database file or not. makemigrations does not check the database.

You can only add a non-nullable field to a model if you add it to a new model and make an initial migration. This is because, after you make that initial migration, Django has no way of knowing whether you deployed your application somewhere else, so it has no way of knowing if there are instances of a model out there. A situation where this would go wrong:

1. Create a model X and makemigrations on your local machine.
2. Deploy your Django application to a server, where the database is populated with instances of model X.
3. Delete your local database, add non-nullable field Y to model X, makemigrations.
4. Deploy you Django application to the server.
5. Problems occur.

The solution here is to either:

- Set the Field to null=True
- Add a default to the model.
- Provide a default when making the migrations.

In your situation, I would say it is ok to provide a one-off default, because it sounds like you have no populated database yet.

Comment: Is there a way to force initial migration to happen again? I mean is there a way to tell Django that this is a fresh installation of the application?

Comment: If you are absolutely sure that there is no database floating around somewhere, you can delete the migration files for that application, and running makemigrations again. Django will then generate a new initial migration for that application.

Comment: A few caveats though (Which in your case would probably not apply):
If the migrations in other applications rely on the migrations you are trying to delete, your makemigrations command will result in all sorts of errors. So only do this if your structure and project is not too complex, and it's best to remove all migrations from all apps, and start fresh. As a general rule: never remove migrations unless you absolutely need to, and if you are sure there is no production database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide  `blank` and `null` True for `high52` field .

```
high52 = models.SomeField(blank=True,null=True)
```

If you don't want so then you can select any of these two options.

For example  If `high52` is `CharField` then you can choose the 1 option and provide some value like `'..'` or you can set defaults in your models.py

Comment: But why it is complaining only for the newly added field. I have other fields in the model that also don't have any of these (null, blank, default).

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while trying to force Django to have Null values in existing records but not allow the creation of new Null records. My solution was to do 2 consecutive migrations, one with `null=True` and the second one removing that.